# youtube chromeless as3 player

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube, youtube-api

I'm goofing around with the new youtube as3 API but got stuck. This is
how far i got (from looking at their sample code).

http://pastie.org/656088

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    Security.allowDomain("*");

    private var player:Object;
    private var loader:Loader;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
    }

    private function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void
    {
        addChild(loader);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("onPlayerQualityChange", onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
    }

    private function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Player ready: " + Object(e).Data);
    }
    private function onPlayerError(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Player error: " + Object(e).Data);
    }
    private function onPlayerStateChange(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Player state: " + Object(e).Data);
    }
    private function onVideoPlaybackQualityChange(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Video quality: " + Object(e).Data);
    }
}
```

I don't really know what the next step is. I get no errors and nothing gets traced. I'm pretty sure that my events are not implemented correctly.

Update:
I followed Amarghosh's answered and did this instead:

```
private function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void
{
  player = Sprite(loader.content);
  addChild(player);
  player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
  player.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
  player.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
  player.addEventListener("onPlayerQualityChange", onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
}
```

Now the onPlayerReady and the onStateChange events fires but i get errors. When tracing Object(e).Data i get this error

`ReferenceError: Error #1069: the property Data was not found for com.google.youtube.event.ExternalEvent and there is no standard value.`
(stranslated from swedish) 
When changing to Object(e.target).Data it traces "undefined" and Object(e.target) traces [object SwfProxy].

If i try `player.loadVideoById("uad17d5hR5s");` i get this error:

`1061: Call to a possibly undefined method loadVideoById through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for all the library confusion, I think I have the answer to your other error though. When you do this `Sprite(loader.content)` you 'force' cast the player to be a sprite, because you want methods of the api I would recommend using a plain old object, because it won't complain about untyped methods:

```
// No particluar type
var player:Object;

private function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void
{
    player = loader.content;
    addChild(player as DisplayObject);

    var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher = player as IEventDispatcher;
    dispatcher.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
    dispatcher.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
    dispatcher.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
    dispatcher.addEventListener("onPlayerQualityChange", onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `player` is supposed to hold the loaded youtube player, change its type from `Object` to something more solid like `Sprite`.

```
private var player:Sprite;
```

Now, I don't know the youtube API, but there is a problem in your `onLoaderInit` method. You should be adding those listeners to the loaded content instead of its `LoaderInfo` object. `LoaderInfo` dispatches events related to the loading process - it's not relevant once the loading is successful. The events mentioned in those calls would be dispatched by the loaded content. Change the method to:

```
private function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void
{
  player = Sprite(loader.content);
  addChild(player);
  player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
  player.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
  player.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
  player.addEventListener("onPlayerQualityChange", onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
}
```

Comment: Great! One step closer. I have updated my post. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a good idea to ask a new question once your problem (that you asked in the question) is solved, rather than continuing to discuss all issues in the same thread.

Comment: It seems that the problem is related to youtubeapi - ask it as another question to get more exposure.

Answer (score 0):

relatively recently youtube released a wrapper library for their chromeless player. You should definitly use this version (you could write it again yourself, but thats reinventing the wheel), check out the tutorial/example on this page

[ActionScript 3.0 Wrapper for Chromeless Player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/articles/youtube_as3_chromeless.html)

Comment: That wrapper was released a quite a while ago and not by youtube. The wrapper is for the as2 API and i want to try out the as3 API.

Comment: I'm sure this is true, but the link above is for the AS3 wrapper library, the library that is for ActionScript 3.0, strictly typed events and everything.

Comment: And I'm sure the wrapper has got strictly typed events and everything but it is still using the old deprecated API.

Comment: I'm sorry Johan you were right, after comparing the url's of the chromeless swf I see http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1 for the wrapper library and http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3 for the new one. Many apologies, I think I may have solved your other problem though....